# What would be a better way to build up my html with C#?

Tags: c#, html, sql, dynamic

I am very new to C# and web forms.  I am building a site that pulls data from a SQL database to present to the viewer.  What suggestions do you have for building HTML, pulling and presenting data from a sql database with C#?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class csusaCentralCallFlows : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        GetCallFlowData();
    }
    else if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GenerateCallFlowDropDown();
    }
}
private void GenerateCallFlowDropDown()
{

    SqlConnection CFPull = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csusaCDB"].ConnectionString);
    string sql = @"
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    CustomerName
                FROM
                    CustomerData
                ";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, CFPull);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    CFPull.Open();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    CFPull.Close();
    string html = "";
    html = "<select name=\"CustomerNameDD\" onChange=\"SubmitForm()\">";
    html += "<option>Select a Call Flow</option>";
    int rowCount = dt.Rows.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        html += "<option>";
        html += dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0);
        html += "</option>";
    }

    html += "</select>";
    DropDownDiv.InnerHtml += html;
}
private void GetCallFlowData()
{

    ResultsDiv.InnerHtml = "";
    string coName = Request.Form["CustomerNameDD"];
    SqlConnection PullDataConn = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csusaCDB"].ConnectionString);
    string sql = @"
                SELECT CustomerData.CustomerName, CallFlowData.contactPhone, CallFlowData.contactEmail, CallFlowData.contactOther
                FROM CallFlowData
                INNER JOIN CustomerData ON CustomerData.CustomerID = CallFlowData.CallFlowID
                WHERE CustomerData.CustomerName LIKE @CustomerName
        ";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, PullDataConn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerName", coName);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    PullDataConn.Open();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    PullDataConn.Close();

    int rowCount = dt.Rows.Count;

    string html = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        html += "<div class='divContainer'>" + 
                    "<table class='resultsTable1'>" + 
                    "<tr><td colspan='2' class='tdCoName'>";
        html += dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0);
        html += "</td></tr>" + 
                    "<tr><td class='contactCat'>HotLine</td>" +
                    "<td class='tdHeadingPadding'>";
        html += dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(1);
        html += "</td></tr>" +
                    "<tr><td class='contactCat'>e-Mail</td>" +
                    "<td class='tdHeadingPadding'>";
        html += dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(2);
        html += "</td></tr>";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString()))
        {
            html += "<tr><td colspan='2' style='height:10px;'></td></tr></table></div>";
        }
        else
        {
            html += "<tr><td class='contactCat'>Other</td><td class='tdHeadingPadding'>";
            html += dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3);
            html += "</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' style='height:10px;'></td></tr></table></div>";
        }

    }

    ResultsDiv.InnerHtml += html;

}
}
```

Comment: If you're just starting with ASP.NET, I suggest that you look into ASP.NET MVC 4 at http://www.asp.net/mvc . There you can find the superb Pluralsight video lessons, which I would strongly recommend you to watch.

Comment: Agree with other with MVC, but if you want use Web Form a good control for present data is ASP.NET Repeater. Check This http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/repeater-controls-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: This question might be a better fit for CodeReview SE.

Comment: Since you are new to C# and learning anyway, I agree that your effort would be best spent learning the latest framework. Start using MVC4, it's actually pretty easy to understand.

Comment: I've spent all day and evening watching some beginner tutorials of MVC4, seems very organized and although there seems to be a lot to it, the concept is very easy to understand.  Thanks for pointing me in a good direction folks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASP.Net web application or ASP.Net web forms application to do this. If it is supposed to be handling very complex logic & high expectation and needed to be operating for longer period then .Net MVC application will be good choice (Its a hell lot of work to get started but really flexible). 
Here is a link to good tutorials..

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhXQS_p1i-HLIftB9Y7Vnxlo